# On what basis does power bi decide to bring in only 1 day of data when run daily?

Tags: powerbi

I am referring to example in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-incremental-refresh#refresh-ranges

It is said that:

> The first refresh operation loads historical data. Subsequent
> refreshes are incremental, and (if scheduled to run daily) perform the
> following operations:
>
> Add a new day of data.
>
> Refresh ten full days up to the current date.
>
> Remove calendar years that are older than five years prior to the
> current date. For example, if the current date is January 1 2019, the
> year 2013 is removed.

When run daily, on what basis does power bi decide to only "add a new day of data"?

Say instead we schedule to run weekly. Then will it add week data?

Does this depend on the refresh schedule or does it depend on value set in "Refresh rows where column is in the last x days"?

If the schedule is to run monthly (1st) then will it still pull one day data (31st) and refresh last 10 day data (21st - 31st)? This it will miss data for 1st to 20th?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI refresh will be determined by the column you setup during Transformation and subsequently the Incremental Refresh configuration, not the refresh frequency.

If you set up the incremental refresh to reload the last 10 days of order dates, then that is what Power BI will reload, whether daily or weekly.  You can further optimise this, by using the Detect Data Changes option to only bring back only days that have changes since the last load.

[image]

If you subsequently set the refresh period to a longer timeframe than you will miss data in Power BI.  So in your example, a 10 day refresh on column x run on 1st of each month, would fail to load the first 20 days.  In this case you would want to set the refresh rows to "Refresh rows where column is in the last 1 **month**", not 10 days.

Comment: So if for some reason refresh fails and is rerun on next day then 1 day data will be missing.

Comment: If you've scheduled one refresh, and it fails, then yes you would be missing data.  Data refresh failures are not handled particularly gracefully in Power BI.  You can warn the data owner by email, but that is not always ideal.  You can also schedule multiple refreshes with overlapping time, to try and minimise the issue, but again not perfect.

Comment: And is there anyway to do a full refresh ?